# Наследоваие UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеются `UserControl'ы`, они все наследуются от `UserControl`. И как сделать чтоб они наследовались от `AbstractClass`, а сам `AbstractClass` от `UserControl`

```
abstract class AbstractClass : UserControl
{
}

public partial class UControlsA:AbstractClass //UserControlA
{
}

public partial class UControlsB:AbstractClass //UserControlB
{
}
```

Comment: и чем вам не нравится то что вы написали?

Answer (score 2):

Напишите в вашем XAML

```
<local:AbstractClass
    x:Class="YourNamespace.UControlsA"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
    ...>
    ...
</local:AbstractClass>
```

Проще всего создать обыкновенный `UserControl`, и отредактировать его потом.